# How can I run a selenium script in the background or minimize mode?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chrome-options

I am writing a script in Selenium WebDriver using C#. I want to run this script in the background or minimize mode. I don't want to display the browser to the user. I tried the Chrome Options class and its properties to accomplish the task but unable to do that.

> What could be the best approach of running the selenium script in the
>   background or minimize mode in Selenium WebDriver using C#?

Answer (score 1):

To minimize:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(-2000, 0);
```

To background use a headless webdriver:

```
WebDriver htmlUnitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

Or for Headless Chrome, see [here](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/5336747), it's not a simple solution though.

**Best approach:** depends on your case. For testing a web app use Chrome minimized. For scraping, use a headless browser.